# How to Move Button Beside Text Boxes in WPF using WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. I have a Button.I want to create Dynamic textBoxes.when ever I  got the focus on dynamic textbox the button move to beside textbox. I dont know how to do this. please help me

```
 <Grid Name="mymy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="243" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="263" Margin="462,105,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="abc" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="232" Margin="0,0,-250,-218" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262" Grid.Row="1"/>
 </Grid>
    <!--<DockPanel Name="mymy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="191" LastChildFill="True" Margin="424,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>-->
```

.cs code

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtSource = new TextBox();
        txtSource.MinHeight = 15;
        txtSource.Width = 100;
        txtSource.Height = 25;
        txtSource.Name = "txtSource";

        //Binding txtBinding = new Binding("PurchaseOrder.PickupSrcCodeName"); /*txtBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;*/

        //txtSource.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, txtBinding);

        ColumnDefinition colDef1;
        colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        mymy.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);

        RowDefinition rowDef1;
        rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
        mymy.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
        ++count;

        abc.Children.Add(txtSource);


        Grid.SetColumn(txtSource, count);
        Grid.SetRow(txtSource, 0);
        txtSource.GotFocus += t_GotFocus;
        txtSource.TextChanged += this.t_TextChanged;
      }

    private void t_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpS0e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
Consider these two things:

1. It's extremely bad habit to change the layout of a grid at run time (and by layout I mean rows and columns)
2. Just the same way that you set your textboxes positions in your grid you can position your button within it as well. You just need to create the rows and columns required by it before head.

My opinion here is you should have a stack layout adding controls to it dynamically. That control then can be custom control consisting of a grid with a text box and a position for button (or maybe a button that can be hidden or visible with a property)

If you like my idea please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx) to know how to create custom controls.